# Check variable does not start with 07 in PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement, process

I want to check if a string starts with 07, if it does do nothing, if it doesn't then process as true...currently using:

```
if (strpos($mobile, '_') !=== 07) {$processed=TRUE;}
```

Just want to make sure I have the code correct.

Comment: Firstly, leading zeros are treated as an octal, use quotes. Not enough code here btw as to what the values are.

Comment: `!===` is not a valid operator!!

Comment: strpos gives you the position of it, so if your string was 07829392 then the strpos of _ would be -1. It does not exist: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php What you want is strpos of '07' === 0.

Comment: "Just want to make sure I have the code correct." Have you _tried it_? You would have discovered the `!===` issue immediately…

Comment: Basically want to check a mobile number imported from a csv is a mobile number i.e. it starts 07. If it doesn't I don't want to import it.

Comment: Would this work? if (strpos($mobile, '07') !== 0) {$processed=TRUE;}

Comment: @GrahamDrummond, again, I urge you to _try it_. Write that code and run it against a few different inputs. That's a big part of what programmers do: write some code and see if it does what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!===` is not valid. [Read about valid comparison operators at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

You're checking for `'_'` ? Is some code missing?

This is how you could check if **07** exists at the start of the string:

```
<?php

$mobile = '0782930423';

if (strpos($mobile, '07') === 0) {
    echo $mobile . " starts with 07";
} else {
    echo $mobile . " does not start with 07";
}

$mobile = '8582930423';

if (strpos($mobile, '07') === 0) {
    echo $mobile . " starts with 07";
} else {
    echo $mobile . " does not start with 07";
}
```

Output:

> 0782930423 starts with 07
>
> 8582930423 does not start with 07

Read more about the `strpos` function [from the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: *"!=== is not valid"* - However true, a link to php.net would be a bonus and outlining "why" it's invalid.

Comment: @viion - testing this option now, seems to work - thank you!